# android Eclipse Count The User Letter input in Word User Input the display to textview the result

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops

I want to create an app in which a user can input a word and input a letter, and application will count number of times that letter is used in word. Here is my code

```
public class LetterCount extends Activity {

    Button CountLetter;
    TextView Result;
    EditText WordCount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lettercounter);

        Button CountLetter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncount);

        CountLetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Declaring The Id in Xml    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberletter);
                EditText WordCount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtletter);
                String input =  WordCount.getText().toString();

                EditText Letter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtletter);
                Char lettercount = Letter.getText();

                //loop for counting the letter in Word
                int charCount = 0;
                for(int i =0 ; i<input.length(); i++){
                    if(input.charAt(i) == lettercount){
                        charCount++;
                    }
                }
               //Displaying the result in Text View
               Result.setText(charCount);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but the app stops working when I click the button. How should I fix this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ??

Comment: Just making sure that I got it right: You want to let use input a word and a letter and count how many times is the letter in that word right? Btw you are not getting any exceptions in debug or something?

Comment: pl share your stack trace.

Comment: send your logcat error

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the view **txtletter** twice. Instead, take another EditText where user can enter the character they want to count, say **letter**

So the view will now be

```
EditText Letter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter);
```

Also, instead of passing int to [**setText**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), convert it to string if you want to display the result of the loop in the textview.

```
            EditText Letter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter); //user will enter which character they want to count
            char lettercount = Letter.getText().toString().charAt(0); //read the character

            //loop for counting the letter in Word
            int charCount = 0;
            for(int i =0 ; i<input.length(); i++){
                if(input.charAt(i) == lettercount){
                    charCount++;
                }
            }
           //Displaying the result in Text View
           Result.setText(charCount + ""); //convert to string before passing to setText
```